# dataTables Search filter by One Column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using datatables.net for my grid view. In search box it is searching from all columns. But i want the scenario like below.

I have a 5 columns, lets say - name, age, number, address, gender. I want all those options in the dropdown and from the dropdown when user select name and enter text in the search box, it will search only in the name column. Like wise if user select age from the drop down, he can search only on age column.

I have seen lot of examples which they are different from what i needed.

Comment: Please show us your code, and what you have tried ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really easy, asked in various ways multiple times - but surprisingly I could not find an exact match. If you have a `<select>` that corresponds to your columns :

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>Seq.</option>
  <option>Name</option>
  <option>Position</option>
  <option>Office</option>
  <option>Start date</option>
  <option>Salary</option>
</select>
```

then you can hijack the searchbox by `.unbind()` and target the column that correspond to the selects' `selectedIndex`  :

```js
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  var colIndex = document.querySelector('#select').selectedIndex;
  table.column( colIndex).search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8fLagfyp/**

BTW: You can reset previous search when the select is changed by

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  table.columns().search('').draw();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. You are the best!  Only functionality I have missed that i didn't know how to unbind and rebind the one column to the search box and I couldn't find anywhere. Thank you very much.And I have added Global option(say default value) in the drop down list. if user select global  it should search across all rows. How can i reset the table to search global? Also when select changed table search box is getting reset. But It can not reset the table to initial. Can you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: ?? Straight forward: If "all columns" is the first item in the `<select>` : `if  (colIndex == 0) {  table.search( this.value ).draw() } else {   table.column( colIndex-1 ).search( this.value ).draw() }` ...You should really add some code to your question.

Comment: I understand sir. But I am new to jquery and trying to implement asp.net Grid View using datatable.js plug-in. So I have been searching for the solution before I ask for help. But unfortunately I couldn't find any. That's why i wasn't add any code to question. And I was asking after user enter text on the search box and after select change it clears the value from the search box using......$('#select').change(function () {
                table.search('').draw();  });.........But table was not reloading to initial data. I was asking to is there anyway to reset the table?

Comment: @crony, yes - use `table.columns().search('').draw();`  -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8fLagfyp/1/** instead of `table.search('').draw();` my bad...

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. That is what I wanted. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello sir, can you find the link below? It's a sort of extended question. Thanks in advance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058982/datatables-header-and-footer-align-position-is-changing

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the searching on other columns except for what is selected by the user. The DataTable has this option `{ "searchable": false, "targets": 0 }` you can dynamically change this configuration object.

Alternatively you also use `columns().search()` to dynamically specify the columns on which search should be performed.

```
e.g. table
    .columns( '.status' )
    .search( 'Important' )
    .draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy, asked in various ways multiple times - but surprisingly I could not find an exact match. If you have a `<select>` that corresponds to your columns :

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlSearch">
    <option value="0">Name</option>
    <option value="1">Position</option>
    <option value="2">Office</option>
    <option value="3">Age</option>
    <option value="4">Start date</option>
    <option value="5">Salary</option>
</select>
```

then implement this JavaScript to get search in separate columns

```
var table;

$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 100,
        dom: 'lrtip',
    });
    var column_no = 0;
    $('#ddlSearch').on('change',function(){
        column_no = Number($(this).val());
    });

    $( '#txtSearch' ).on( 'input', function () {
        if ( table.columns([column_no]).search() !== $( '#txtSearch' ).val() ) {
            table.columns([column_no]).search( $( '#txtSearch' ).val() ).draw();
        }
    } );
});
```

for example try this https://jsfiddle.net/07rnpgs1/

All the best