# Append custom control to dom using dataTables with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have added a select(dropdown) for datatables search box for searching per column and trying to add that select to searchbox as below->

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 dom: '<l<"toolbar">f>rtip',
            language: {
                search: "_INPUT_", //To remove Search Label
                searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
            }
})  
$("div.toolbar").html(select);
```

CSS

```
.toolbar {
        float: right;
    }
```

It actually worked on fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/32v2qpj1/5/

Surprisingly length and filter position has been changing when I implemented the same on my .aspx page like below image. Bootstrap row and col grids are missing whenever I use dom. It adding as a 2 seperate rows for length and search and as same at footer. I tried examples from https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom to check if my code is wrong. It's just re-positioning when use DOM!

[image: datatable alignment missing]

I have no idea why it is re-positioning when only added dom. I was wondering is there any other way to add select control to the search box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. If you set the `dom` option, then you overwrite the default `dom` setting which in dataTables with Bootstrap is :

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

There is no reason for injecting a `.toolbar` when we have a predefined setup like this. Instead give the filter section a little more space :

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'l><'col-sm-7'f>>" +
```

and define a maximum width for the `#select` :

```css
select#select {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Finally add standard Bootstrap classes to the `#select` :

```html
<select id="select" class="form-control input-sm">
```

and append the select to `.dataTables_filter` :

```js
$(".dataTables_filter").append(select);
```

This give the responsive experience we want from Bootstrap.

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/32v2qpj1/6/**

---

**NB**: Remember to remove `jquery.dataTables.min.css` if you use bootstrap! Instead, style the `<table>` the Bootstrap way :

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: Greatly Appreciated sir for the help! I made a small change to your code because using .append(dom element) not working on IE and error-ed "select is undefined ". So changed $(".dataTables_filter").append(select); to... let el = document.querySelector('#select'); $(".dataTables_filter").append(el); Then it's working fine on IE. Thanks again Sir!